# Checkbox click event not fired

Tags: jquery

I got this js (also tried "change" with same result)

```
$("input[class='tag-checkbox']").live("click",function(){
    var thisCheck = $(this);
    if (thischeck.is (':checked')){
        var tag = $(this).val();
        $("#tag-field").val(tag);
        return false;
    }
});
```

which should set the value of this checkbox

```
<input class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="' . $value['name'] . '" />
```

into this textfield

```
<input id="tag-field" type="text" name="product-tag" />
```

But the event is not fired and the textfield is unchanged. I have no error messages so is something wrong with the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using directly `$(this)` :

```
$("input[class='tag-checkbox']").live("click",function(){

    if ($(this).is (':checked')){
        var tag = $(this).val();
        $("#tag-field").val(tag);
        return false;
    }
});
```

working example at : http://jsfiddle.net/hZVwE/

anyway the problem in your script is that you made a typo on thisCheck (once C is capital and then is not)

Comment: it did work now, guess the js file (external) was cached the first time, I'll accept your answer as soon as the timelimit is out, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.tag-checkbox").change(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var tag = $(this).val();
        $('#tag-field').val(tag);
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: It does work. I just made a typo writing ($this) instead of $(this). Check the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable in the if statement is misspelled. It should be "thisCheck", but you have "thischeck" (no capital C). Once you change that, it works.

Answer (score 0):

you have two case for naming of thisCheck

corrected code is

```
 $("input[class='tag-checkbox']").live("click",function(){
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        if (thisCheck.is (':checked')){
            var tag = $(this).val();
            $("#tag-field").val(tag);
            return false;
        }

});
```

demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/M2xUH/4/

some suggetsion.

in place of using  `input[class='tag-checkbox']` you can directly use jquery class selector. as

```
input.tag-checkbox
```

second why you really require `thisCheck` you can directly use `this` ?